# PHP Smart Image Resizer returns broken image

Tags: php, image, iis, resize, on-the-fly

I'm using the [Smart Image Resizer](http://shiftingpixel.com/2008/03/03/smart-image-resizer/) plugin to resize images.  I've been testing on a local server for a while, and now when I uploaded to the server, the image doesn't pull up.

There's really no code to post-has anyone ever had this problem, and if so, is there a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Since there is no code to post, you'll need to make yourself sure all the configurations you gave when testing locally are for sure migrated for the production version. Refer to documentation and check for server requirements later. Not a single idea after this point.

Comment: Save the broken image and open in a text editor. Do you see any php errors at the top of the page?

Comment: @JonathanKuhn nope...

Comment: Maybe read the documentation? Maybe it is a wrong image type?

Comment: @putvande it worked fine on the local server...it's just a normal JPG file

Comment: Are you sure the server is configured to be able to use the resizer (gd library etc.)?

Comment: Did you see any output or just an empty file when saved? I'm assuming the server is not showing errors (display_errors and error_reporting). Perhaps check the server error log. If you see something like `fatal error undefined function imagecreate` the gd extension is probably not installed.

Answer (score 0):

Found the error-I had changed the code to go into a specific directory for the images.  The script was removing the slashes from the image variable, so it was looking for `imagesIMG_1234.JPG` instead of `images/IMG_1234.JPG`.

Thanks!